# E488 error when defining a custom command in vim

Tags: vim

I'm trying to create a shortcut to an existing command in vim. Specifically, I'm setting up eclim, and would like to call the :LocateFile command using just :LF. I've defined it like so:

```
command LF LocateFile
```

This works fine with no arguments, but I get an "E488: Trailing characters" if I give it a filename argument:

```
:LF MyFile
```

I'm thinking I need to stick an nargs in there somewhere, but I can't find any examples of how it should be used in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is the [`cmdalias`](https://github.com/vim-scripts/cmdalias.vim) plugin - it should be able to achieve exactly the thing you're looking for - here i copied from [vim-wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Tabclose_instead_of_quit-all)

```
function! InitPlugins()
  call CmdAlias('LF', 'LocateFile')
  au! InitPlugins VimEnter
endfunction

aug InitPlugins
  au!
  au VimEnter * :call InitPlugins()
aug END
```

Comment: Actually, I think cabbr alone would be enough to achieve what I want. Also, I figured out how to do what I wanted using 'command', I just had the syntax wrong. This works: command -nargs=* LF LocateFile <args>